# React: Can not use HTML tags in Lerna

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about Lerna. 
I have installed it on my desktop and all React dependencies, and now, everything is working,but... 
Lerna creates jsx files in packages folder. I have created mine js (not jsx) file like this:

```
import React from 'react'

function Hello(){
return (
<h1>Hello there!</h1>
)
}

export default Hello
```

When I start my React project I have an error that says:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token
```

I have installed babel loader but It doesn't resolve this problem.
h1 tag or any other html tag is not recognized by Lerna.
So what do you suggest me to do to resolve this issue?

If this can help, I have been working this by reading this article: https://michalzalecki.com/solve-code-sharing-and-setup-project-with-lerna-and-monorepo/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you created '.js' file, and interpret it as a JS code (not JSX), 
you must return a valid JS expression:

```
function Hello(){
    return "<h1>Hello there!</h1>";
}
```